# Update inside pl/sql Trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have table

```
messages ( 
  id number, 
  mess varchar2(4000), 
  short_mess(100) )
```

I want to create trigger that does something like that:

```
INSERT into messages ( id, message ) values ( some_id, some_message)
```

And then in table `messages` I would like to have `( some_id, some_message, some_message_shortcut)`

My triggers looks like this:

```
create or replace trigger "MESSAGES_T1"
AFTER
insert on "MESSAGES"
for each row
begin
UPDATE  MESSAGES set "short_mess" = 'aaa'
where id = :new.id;
end;
```

But when i try to inserd new row I get error

```
ORA-04091: table FIRSTAPP.MESSAGES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "FIRSTAPP.MESSAGES", line 2 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIRSTAPP.MESSAGES'
```

How should i do this? ( `'aaa'` was just for testing purposes ) 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update, just assign the new value. But you need a `BEFORE` trigger for that to work, you can't modify the new row in an `AFTER` trigger:

```
create or replace trigger "MESSAGES_T1"
  BEFORE insert on "MESSAGES"
  for each row
begin
  :new.short_mess := 'aaa';
end;
/
```